# Is there a mathematical symbol I can use for "where" in this?

Tags: notation

To solve   ${x^2} - 15x + 56 = 0$ use the formula   $\ x = \frac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {{b^2} - 4ac} }}{{2a}}$ where b =  - 15,a = 1,c = 56.  Is there a mathematical symbol I can use for "where" in this?

Comment: No! Maybe comma $","$ is the best symbolic way to write it out instead.

Comment: Personally I think it reads better with 'where' left in rather than trying to compress the notation any more.

Comment: (let a in f a) and (f a where a is ...) are already mathematical constructs; there's no need for a symbol. They are equivalent to (\a. f a)(b)

Comment: I like the "where", but my Latex editor doesn't like me putting words and spaces into equations and it breaks the flow if I have to switch to plain text.

Comment: surely there's a workaround for making it usable; latex tends to be very clunky without the right modules

Answer (score 7):

$$
x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\bigg|_{b=-15, a=1, c=56}
$$

Comment: Reminds me of calculus.